# Pure JavaScript Page Loading Effect

Tags: javascript

I have created simple page loading animation using JavaScript. 
**I want add this animation to all of pages so i create `loading.start();` method for it. So that `loading.start();` method is working well but `loading.complete();` method not working. So it seems having an error**

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of null

Currently body is not found  `loading` element. I append it when body is loading. After i want to remove it.
Help To Fix This

**Here My JavaScript Code**

```
var loading = {
    start: function () {
        document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="loading">LOADING</div>');
    },
    complete: function () {
        var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
        loading.remove(loading);
    }
};

document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        loading.complete();
    }
});

window.onload = function(){
  loading.start();
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert the paragraph with the `id` of `loading` only when the `window` has loaded (In this state the `readyState` is already equal to `"complete"`). What you are trying to do is fetching the paragraph when the `readyState` is equal to `complete` but at this stage, **No paragraph is inserted into the DOM because the window.onload() event hasn't fired yet.** Therefore the returned value will always be equal to `null`.

What you need to do is remove the `window.onload` so that `start` method of `loading` object literal fires immediately before the `readyState` is equal to `complete` just like so:

```js
var loading = {
  start: function() {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="loading">LOADING</div>');
  },
  complete: function() {
    var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
    console.log(loading);
    loading.remove(loading);
  }
};
loading.start();
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  console.log(document.readyState);
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    loading.complete();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**New Edit :** 
You cannot find the div because when `document.readyState` is complete, the div has not been added to the DOM. It is added after. If you create the div directly in HTML, it is present when the body has finished loading.

But, I've been searching deeper and discovered that `document.readyState` will stay to 'complete' after the page has been loaded for the first time. You can modify the DOM after it, the event listener won't detect anything and `readyState` won't change. 
Then if you want to animate at the very beginning, it's possible with `document.readyState`. But if you want to animate later, you need to change the structure of your code to make it work. Add an event listener specific to the element you animate.

Look at this code for a CSS animation :

```
<div id="sample" class="square"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="this.style.display='none'; loading();">Start Animation</a>

<style type="text/css">
.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
.square.hide {
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
//start
var sample = document.getElementById('sample');
function loading() {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div id="loading">LOADING</div>');
    sample.className += ' hide';
}
//CSS animation
function cssAnimation(){
    var transitions = {
        'transition':'transitionend',
        'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
        'MozTransition':'transitionend',
        'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }
    var element = document.createElement('fake');
    var x;
    for (x in transitions) {
        if (element.style[x] !== undefined) { return transitions[x]; }
    }
}
//detect end & launch CSS animation
sample.addEventListener(cssAnimation(), function() {
    document.getElementById("loading").remove();
});
cssAnimation();
</script>
```

Comment: Lambic, I have tried to fix this.it doesn't work. Can you edit your answer with working code please. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, new edit. It looks like the structure of the code cannot do what you want. I put working example code.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem:

```
var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
```

Check the Id "loading". An element of that Id is not found, so cannot be removed.

Comment: Currently body is not found  `loading` element. I append it when body is loading. After i want to remove it.